# Rowspan with AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need some help with **ng-repeat** of angularJs. I'm trying to render a table using **colspan** with the following json:

```
var json = {
   "actorActress":[
      {
         "name":"Angelina Jolie",
         "age":45,
         "rowspan":2
      },
      {
         "name":"Brad Pitt",
         "age":48,
         "rowspan":3
      }
   ],
   "Films":[
      {
         "film":"Mr & Mrs Smith",
         "other_info":"info1"
      },
      {
         "film":"Tomb Raider",
         "other_info":"info2"
      },
      {
         "film":"Troy",
         "other_info":"info1"
      },
      {
         "film":"Mr & Mrs Smith",
         "other_info":"info2"
      },
      {
         "film":"Fight Club",
         "other_info":"info1"
      }
   ]
}
```

And this is the table that I'm trying to render:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

**Update - Original Array**
This is the original array that I receive from Data Base

```
var OriginallyJson = [
                       {"name": "Angelina Jolie", "age": 45, "film": "Mr & Mrs Smith", "other_info": "info1"},
                       {"name": "Angelina Jolie", "age": 45, "film": "Tomb Raider", "other_info": "info1"},
                       {"name": "Brad Pitt", "age": 48, "film": "Mr & Mrs Smith", "other_info": "info2"}, ... ,]
```

Comment: Can you change the array structure? Maybe using map to create a new array and not modifying the original.

Comment: Yes, I changed to this structure because I thought it would be easier render the table. Initially the json variable was an array with repeated data. I updated my question with the original array structure

Answer (score 3):

It would be achieved by using `ng-repeat` with the combination of `limit` filter correctly.

**HTML**

```
<table border="1px solid red">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="25%">Name</th>
      <th width="25%">Age</th>
      <th width="25%">Films</th>
      <th width="25%">Other Information</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="person in json.actorActress">
      <td width="25%">{{person.name}}</td>
      <td width="25%">{{person.age}}</td>
      <td width="50%" colspan="2">
        <table width="100%" border="1px">
          <tr width="100%" ng-repeat="f in json.Films | limitTo: person.rowspan: calculateInitialIndex($index)">
            <td width="50%">
              {{f.film}}
            </td>
            <td width="50%">
              {{f.other_info}}
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Code**

```
function calculate(startIndex, index, result){
  if(startIndex == 0 && index == 0) return result;
  result = result + $scope.json.actorActress[--index].rowspan
  if(index == 0) return result;
  return calculate(startIndex, index, result)
}

$scope.calculateInitialIndex = function(currentIndex) {
  var result = 0;
  return calculate(currentIndex, currentIndex, result);
}
```

[Working Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/IJvRPLF22Kq0jZ0BJowl?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks Pankaj, it's a good answer, but do you think that is possible render the table without using nested tables?

Comment: @Nands its quite tough.. you have to reformat the JSON structure then, I'd recommend to do that, so that solution would also become easier :)